# Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17)

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':external_path:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).

  Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
  Learn more about JVM-target validation: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation 

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions { jvmTarget =17 }
```

its app\build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
    }
```

i followed answer form here and yet same probelm

i updated jdk to latest version
kotlin to latest version
and my gradle settings is blocked out cannot view it

i followed answer form here and yet same probelm

i updated jdk to latest version
kotlin to latest version
and my gradle settings is blocked out cannot view it

and i cant find this setting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e72uR.png)